# Demanding $U(1)$ symmetry on Dirac Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, wavefunction, dirac-equation, gauge-invariance

For some personal studies I tried to derive the $U(1)$ invariant Dirac Equation as follows (I’ll be assuming natural units):

$$i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi-m\psi=0.$$

Then applying a $U(1)$ transformation $\psi’\rightarrow\psi e^{i\phi(x^\mu)}=\psi e^{i\phi}$

Substituting into the Dirac Equation and then simplifying:

$i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu(\psi e^{i\phi})-m\psi e^{i\phi}=0$

$i\gamma^\mu(e^{i\phi}\partial_\mu\psi+i\psi e^{i\phi}\partial_\mu\phi)-m\psi e^{i\phi}=0$

$i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu\psi+i\psi\partial_\mu\phi)-m\psi=0$

We see there is an extra term, so to erase this we insert the EM field:

$i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+iA_\mu)\psi-m\psi=0$

Then because $A_\mu’\rightarrow A_\mu-\partial_\mu\phi$ under a $U(1)$ transformation, the Dirac Equation (and hence the wave equation) will remain invariant at every point.

Is this a correct line of reasoning, or am I missing terms in the “edited” Dirac Equation. If so, where are the errors in the derivation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You algebra is correct.

When we say a theory is ${\rm U}(1)$ invariant we usually mean invariant under *global* transformations in which your $\phi$ is independent of $x$ and $t$. This condition is sufficient for the conservation of the associated charge and to derive $\partial_\mu \bar\psi \gamma^\mu \psi=0$.

If you want invariance under *local* transformations in which $\phi$ does depend on $x$ and $t$ then you need  a gauge theory with its gauge field $A_\mu$. The two symmetries are different things. Indeed "gauge symmetry" is not so much a symmetry as a redundancy in the description.